# Is it safe to use nicotine to enhance performance?

Tags: supplements, safety, athletic-performance

Nicotine seems to be a performance-enhancing drug, like caffeine. But because nicotine is associated with smoking, it seems dangerous to try a nicotine patch to get better gym results.

Is it safe? And if so, how should I dose it? Are there any unwanted side effects?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether nicotine could provide a net benefit to one's exercise.  Consider [the Examine.com 'Nicotine' article](https://examine.com/supplements/Nicotine/).

Answer (score 3):

here is a piece of an article I read on your question. 
"The performance-enhancing effects of nicotine included increased "vigilance and cognitive function" and "reduced stress and body weight", the laboratory reported after a year-long study published by the Forensic Science International journal."
link to this article is as follows http://www.foxsports.com.au/more-sports/wada-to-move-towards-declaring-nicotine-a-performance-enhancing-drug/news-story/2ae65758bffffa095bcdd3aa29ca0b70
using Nicotine as an average Joe I Don't think it is much of a performance enhancing drug. The Anti Doping Agency made it a banded substance because they are dealing with world class athletes. Where an Athlete might try to find any kind of slight advantage to use in competition. Reducing stress in a sport like boxing might be considered performance enhancing. I can go on and on with examples but I think you get my point. I wouldn't try using a nicotine patch to reach a higher level of gains if what you are doing is lifting weights. You will get better results using creatine or something similar to creatine. Hope this helps you.